# Shell Linux - output split mp4 with number

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shell

I use the command split on Windows and I have no problem, but I have not number with shell on Linux and I have an error on output.

Example:

```
fichier = "toto.mp4"

tab=(${fichier//./ })
$Lienffmpeg " -i "$fichier" -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 00:01:00 -reset_timestamps 1 "${tab[0]}"%03d.mp4"
```

I should have the following output:

```
toto001.mp4
toto002.mp4
...
```

and I have:

```
toto%03d.mp4
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?
I tried several combinations but I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

First get the filename:

`filename=$(basename toto.mp4)`

Strip the filename from its extension:

`sinext="${filename%.*}"`

Then lets clean up your `ffmpeg` command:

`ffmpeg  -i "$filename" -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 00:01:00 -reset_timestamps 1 -start_number 1 "$sinext%03d.mp4"`

The output should look as following:

```
toto000.mp4
toto001.mp4
toto002.mp4
...
```

Comment: What part of your change fixed the problem with the filename literally containing ``%03d``?  In other words, what caused that?

Comment: @Scott wrong usage of quotes probably. I cannot reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: I have try with your code, it works.
Thanks you very much. :)